# Why does my local checkout fails on Spartacus 1.5?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

### The Error

```
*polyfills.js:3050 GET https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/powertools/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=/checkout&lang=en&curr=USD 404*
```

I am not able to perform checkout on both of my local powertools and electronics sites. The Chrome console log complains about the error shown above. Also, I have tried opening the given link in a new tab and it says `No content page found matching the provided label or id: /checkout`. Checked the WCMS Pages in my local Backoffice, I couldn't find any page with label or id as "checkout".

Could it be that I have to setup my local with the `b2c_for_spartacus`? (I have setup mine with `b2c_b2b_acc_oms` recipe instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed your SAP Commerce instance with the Spartacus Sample Data AddOn?  The standard Powertools data setup will not include this, but the additions in spartacussampleadataaddon do.  Please see links/instructions in https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud/

If installed/setup correctly you should have a content page with UID=*Checkout* in the *powertools-spaContentCatalog* content catalog